# Hide Cursor script doesn't work correctly in Unity 5

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, cursor, unityscript

I've a simple hide cursor script attached in the "FirstPersonCharacter" GameObject and doesn't work correctly.

```
#pragma strict

var blocked = false;

function Start () {
    blockCursor (false);
}

function blockCursor (blocked) {
    this.blocked = blocked;
    Screen.lockCursor = blocked;
    Cursor.visible = !blocked;
}

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e")) {
        blockCursor(!blocked);
    }
}
```

This script works perfectly in Unity 4.6, but now in Unity 5 when I press "E" the cursor moves to the center and doesn't hide.
**What I'm doing bad? :(**

Comment: I tested your script in Unity 5 on OSX and it works fine for me. The E key hides and shows the cursor as expected. I simply created a new project and attached the script to the Main Camera.

Comment: Bugs... I think... a while ago that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To lock the cursor then center it, you will just have to change your blockCursor function to:

```
function blockCursor (blocked) {
    this.blocked = blocked;
    Cursor.visible = !blocked;
    Cursor.lockState = blocked ? CursorLockMode.Locked : CursorLockMode.None;
}
```

This should solve your problems.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You mean something like this?

Comment: #pragma strict

var blocked = false;

function Start () {
    blockCursor (false);
}

function blockCursor (blocked) {
    this.blocked = blocked;
    bool Screen.lockCursor = blocked;
    Cursor.visible = !blocked;
}

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e")) {
        blockCursor(!blocked);
    }
}

This give me an error. And If I change to "Cursor.visible" the cursor only hides and doesn't center. Oh.

Comment: @gecko I think I confused you. Since you want the cursor to hide and be locked, look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Code for Lock/Hide Cursor Unity 5

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HideLockCursorA : MonoBehaviour
{
void Start ()
  {
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
  }
                  void Update ()
            {
                    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
                    Cursor.visible = false;
            }
}
```

Video: [youtube.com/watch?v=2bWoRTRT_DU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bWoRTRT_DU)